# Finding value in column of data frame corresponding to two values in another column

Tags: pandas

Consider the following.

```
d=pd.DataFrame([[1,'a'],[1,'b'],[2,'c'],[2,'a'],[3,'c'],[4,'a'],[4,'c']],columns=['A','B'])
```

I want to find values in column A that correspond to 'a' and 'c' in column B ({2,4}). So I wrote the following query.

```
d[d.A.isin(set(d[d.B=='c'].A)) & d.B=='a'].A
```

My logic is that since

```
set(d[d.B=='c'].A
```

returns all values in A that have 'c' associated with them it should return {2,3,4} and it does return that. I then consider all the rows starting with {2,3,4}, and of these rows choose the ones that have 'a' associated with them in B so that I get all the values in A that have 'c' and 'a associated with them. But my query returns an empty set. It should return {2,4}. Can someone help debug? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) 
to check if the unique values ​​in A have associated the value 'a' and the value 'c' in B:

```
new_df=d[d.groupby('A')['B'].transform(lambda x: x.eq('a').any()&x.eq('c').any())]
print(new_df)

   A  B
2  2  c
3  2  a
5  4  a
6  4  c
```

---

```
unique_values=new_df['A'].unique()
print(unique_values)
#[2 4]
```

**Details:**

You want to find what values ​​in `A` have associates in `B` both `'a'` and `'c'`. Then you can use `groupby('A')` to perform operations on dataframe based on the unique values ​​in row A:

```
d.groupby('A')
```

**It allows to operate in groups based on the values ​​in A:**

```
   A  B
0  1  a
1  1  b

2  2  c
3  2  a

4  3  c

5  4  a
6  4  c
```

---

Now for each group using [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) we check if 'c' and also 'a' is in column `B`:

```
d.groupby('A')['B'].transform(lambda x: x.eq('a').any()&x.eq('c').any())

0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
5     True
6     True
Name: B, dtype: bool
```

- [`Series.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html) is used to check if **any** value in Series B for
  each group is 'c' or if any value in Series B is 'a'
- [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) here is similar than use `'=='`

---

This series is used to perform a [`Boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

```
new_df=d[d.groupby('A')['B'].transform(lambda x: x.eq('a').any()&x.eq('c').any())]
print(new_df)

   A  B
2  2  c
3  2  a
5  4  a
6  4  c
```

Finally using [`Series.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) 
we access the unique values ​​of A of the dataframe new_df:

```
unique_values=new_df['A'].unique()
print(unique_values)
#[2 4]
```

Comment: Sorry for not explain.Solution updaed. See section : Details.
Do not hesitate to ask if you have any doubt:)

Comment: d.groupby ('A) [' B '] means that for each group generated from column A, column B is selected. Then x in `.transform (lambda x: x.eq (' a '). any () & x.eq ('c'). any ()) `represents the values ​​of B for each group.

Comment: That is, for each group the values ​​of the Series B are transformed according to the function defined by: `lambda x: x.eq ('a'). Any () & x.eq ('c'). Any ()`

Comment: What is the issue with my query? Thank you.

Comment: You forget `()`. `d[d.A.isin(set(d[d.B=='c'].A))&(d.B=='a')].A` or `d[d.A.isin(set(d[d.B=='c'].A))&d.B.eq('a')].A` is correct

Comment: & takes precedence over ==. Thank you. I was perplexed for a long time because I was sure the logic was right.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `filter`

```
d.groupby('A').filter(lambda x : pd.Series(['a','c']).isin(x['B']).all()).A.unique()
Out[213]: array([2, 4], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: @user2371765 groupby A, check is all a or c in B , and keep that group

Comment: What does x['B'] mean? What is the actual value of x in lambda x:pd.Series...?